# Android: Using button to load content of another tab and avoiding a reload when tab is clicked

Tags: android, tabs, android-tabhost, tabview

In my project I am using four tabs. I am having a listview of music to be played in one tab and when one clicks on a given song it is loaded and played on another tab 'play' tab. it is currently working perfectly (when one clicks on the song it is played on the 'play' tab and if one selects another song the previous one is overridden). My problem is when one clicks on the 'play' tab itself, not the song the tab is reloaded which is not what i want. The song should continue playing when the tab is clicked but a new song loaded when another song is clicked from the list tab.

Assistance will be highly appreciated

Comment: You're probably overriding some `OnClick()` function, but without the code (The code from your `MainActivity`, in particular the part which opens the "play" tab), there's isn't much that can be done.

Comment: Maybe to put the question clearly, how do i differentiate between  a tab load as a result of a button click from that of a tab click

Comment: Please add your code for clarity